# MS Access Application to ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, vbscript, scripting

I have a project to convert a massive MS Access application to asp.net. unfortunately I'm not that good in VBscripts therefore, I was wondering if I can run the same MS Access (as backend) on asp.net and change the interface little bit perhaps. accepting any other suggestions.

Comment: You can keep the access database for the tables/queries but you have to create the forms in asp.net and databind to the access database. Have a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *possible* to use an Access database as a back-end to an ASP.NET application, but according to the [ASP.NET Data Access FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database):

> Microsoft strongly recommends against using Access in web applications.

(Click the link above for details.)

If the ASP.NET application will encounter anything more than the absolute lightest of traffic (especially if the Access application truly is "massive") then you would be well advised to convert the Access database to SQL Server and use that as the back-end for your ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ADO.net with c# to interact with access DB.
I think every thing else is static...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the **OledbConnection, OledbCommand, OledbAdaptor** and others as you do it in its as easy as it is for **SQL**

Check this question

[How to open connection with Microsoft Access database in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024660/how-to-open-connection-with-microsoft-access-database-in-c-sharp)

Or Follow this 
[Microsoft Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)