# Uploading a asp.net website to azure with Access database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-access, azure

I have a finished web project, fully functioning, i wanted to upload it to the net. i started the windows azure trial to host my website on it.
my website has an App data and App Code folder i added, I'm using an Access database, but when i published it through visual studio and the app data folder exists in the root, although it seems to have a problem connecting to the database.  i already have an access database file in my app data folder. 
how do i setup an access database on azure and connect it to my website?
how do i properly upload an asp.net website?

Answer (score 0):

Connection to Access DB requires JET OLE DB driver installed on the machine trying to the connection. This driver usually comes with Microsoft Office or as a [separate download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734).

Check [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024660/how-to-open-connection-with-microsoft-access-database-in-c-sharp) for some more details.

However with Azure Web Sites you neither have Office nor can you install any third party software.

A viable solution for you would be to migrate your Access Database to a [Azure SQL Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336279.aspx).