# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Unrecognized database format

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, exception

I tried to open the access database. I can open it from the Server Explorer from Visual Studio, and I can browse all tables and the other data. But if I tried to do it programmatically, I get the exception like in the topic.
I used the same ConnectionString, I copy it. What is the reason?

```
var cs ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\\Data\\Kadry2002.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
var connection = new OleDbConnection(cs);
connection.Open();
```

Comment: Next time please do some research before you post a possibly duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024660/how-to-open-connection-with-microsoft-access-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open connection with Microsoft Access database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024660/how-to-open-connection-with-microsoft-access-database-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Post is not duplicate!

Comment: Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0

Comment: I've another problem, because in the same platform I can connect to my database using VS Server Explorer. Next I copy ConnectionString from the connection properties. Using the same ConnectionString I tried to connect to this database from my program, but this time I get the exception. Ok, it began to work when I replaced ConnectionString with "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Kadry2002.mdb". Problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, it began to work when I replaced ConnectionString with "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Kadry2002.mdb". Problem is solved.

Comment: If it is not a duplicate indeed please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this issue. It began to work when I replaced ConnectionString with

```
var cs = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Kadry2002.mdb";
```